# Find non-zero row index

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix z (say 200x5) where only one element is non-zero in each row. What would be the most efficient way of finding that index without using for loops.

For example:

```
z=[1 0 0;0 0 1];
a=findRow(z)
```

where a should display:

```
[1 3]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Should we do your job / homework? Will we get your payment / diploma afterwards? *shrug*

Comment: Since I found the answer, should I delete it as well? "We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge". I also find it interesting that people are pretty quick to downvote compared to upvoting.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk did you find it on SO? Post a link and we'll mark it as a duplicate

Comment: @Dan No, went back and took a second look at 'find' documentation. Should I be deleting this if I'm racking up downvotes already?

Comment: Up to you, if you feel the question doesn't actually help people find the answer and the answers below don't add anything for you then delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that 'find' is the solution, except that I have to transpose z:

```
[rowidx,~]=find(z');
```

edit: Have to transpose it first because matlab finds things column first. Therefore the order of row indices is off if you don't transpose.

Comment: Why not just use the second output instead of transposing?

Comment: I tried that with a bigger matrix. The order in which the rowidx appears is different (matlab finds things column first).

Comment: Good point! You should add that to your answer (with a small example)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a matrix with mostly `0` elements, you could consider using [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) matrices which are designed to be spatially efficient in such cases:

```
z = sparse([1,0,0;0,0,1]);
```

You can still just use `find` to get your answer

```
[~,idx] = find(z);
```